# Read integer from binary file in Python

Tags: python, c, binaryfiles

I have the following snippet of C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
  int a = 1308901095;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("file", "wb");
  fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
  fclose(fp);
  printf("Done\n");
}
```

This will write the "a" integer in file "file", in binary form.

How I can read this number in Python?

Comment: Small tip: If you're transferring this binary file between computers, be sure to consider endianness and the size of your int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following.

```
from struct import *
f = open('file', 'rb')
print unpack('<i', f.read(4))[0]
f.close()
```

note that using '<' about your machine is little endian or not.

Comment: You should replace '>' or '<' by '@' to use native endianess.
Source: http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment

Comment: @Leo: Presuming the file is being read by the same machine (architecture) as the one that did the writing.

Comment: @john, Yes tou are totally right about that, I was just "completing" your answer.